# Reading virtual attribute from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently reading model attributes from a string:

```
Contact['name']
```

However i have a virtual attribute that i would like to access in the same way, by using a string:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  def special_name
    'SPECIAL NAME'
  end
end
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `send` with a string or symbol:

```
Contact.send('special_name')
```

Comment: legend! #send access both attributes and virtual attributes.

Comment: As well as every other public or private method. Be adviced. :)

Answer (score 0):

via send method you can call via string

```
Contact.send('special_name')
```

Log:

```
[7] pry(main)> User.first.send("full_name")
=> "Jack Jones"
[8] pry(main)> User.first.full_name
=> "Jack Jones"
```